# TypeError: retrieve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry'

Tags: python

I keep getting this issue in my code when I try to use the retrieve command that I had made, I want the button named 'retrieve' to get the information in the entry box. This will then trigger the strGame command.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: retrieve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'entry'
```

My code:

```
from tkinter import *



verif = False
true=True
items=['pistol','knife','sword']
command=False

root=Tk()
root.iconbitmap('GameLogo.ico')

strvar=StringVar()

root.title('RPG Game')
root.geometry('900x600')
root.resizable(False,False)

frame1 = Frame(root, relief=RAISED)
frame1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=10, pady=10)
entry = Entry(frame1).pack(fill=X)
def retrieve(entry):
       result=entry.get()
       return result
retreive = Button(frame1, command=retrieve, text="Click to input").pack(fill=X)

def srtGame():
              try:
                     if retrieve(e1)==str('drop'):
                            print("HELLO")
                            command = True
                            print ("Your inventory:", items)
                            dropItem = input("Which item do you want to drop? ")
                            for i in range(len(items)):
                                   if items[i] == dropItem:
                                          items.remove(dropItem)
                                          print("Your", dropItem,"has been dropped. ")
                                          print("Your inventory", items)
                                          verif = True
                     if verif == False and command == True:
                            print("You don't have that item. Please enter another command.")

              except:
                     IndexError

StartGame = Button(frame1, text="Start game.", relief=RAISED, command=srtGame).pack(fill=X)
GameOutput = Label(frame1, textvariable=strvar, relief=RAISED).pack(fill=X)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Clicking on a button is an event, so you can have `event` as a parameter instead of `entry`, Try this if it works

Comment: Don't use `retrieve` as a name to both a function and a button.

Comment: Remove `entry` from the function parameter. Unless you have a reason for accepting it as a parameter the line after you define it.

Comment: Please check my answer below, for working code. Also, I would strongly recommend you to learn more in depth, before jumping into making an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous errors in this program, which I will clarify here.

#### Useless variable assignments

The lines that goes like:
`widgetVar = Widget(args).geometry(args)`

Such as:
`entry = Entry(frame1).pack(fill=X)`
`retreive = Button(frame1, command=retrieve, text="Click to input").pack(fill=X)`

Is surely not doing what you intended. By chaining the construction of the widget along with geometry call, what really happens is: **`Widget(...)` returns an instance, on which `pack()` or other geometry manager is called, that in turn returns `None`.**

Hence all these variables are `None`, and if you need to store a reference you should break it down to two different lines of code.

#### Unnecessary "middlemen"

As I understand, you want your game to start (probably load another window/screen) on clicking `Start game`.

You can just add code to check the `Entry` contents when the user presses `Start game` directly, instead of having a button to `Input` that really does nothing useful as such.

#### Understand Tkinter `var`s

The point of using Tkinter `var`s is to avoid explicitly accessing the Widget to check data that it contains. For example, if you bind `StringVar` to the Entry, you no longer need to access the `Entry` object directly.

#### Mixing command-line and GUI

I would recommend using the `Dialog` in Tkinter, that can be used to create a pop-up with a text field, to ask the user for which item to drop.

### Working Code

```
from Tkinter import *

items = ['pistol', 'knife', 'sword']

root = Tk()

strvar = StringVar()

root.title('RPG Game')
root.geometry('900x600')
root.resizable(False, False)

frame1 = Frame(root, relief=RAISED)
frame1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y, padx=10, pady=10)
entry = Entry(frame1, textvariable=strvar)
entry.pack(fill=X)


def srtGame():
    if strvar.get() == str('drop'):
        print("HELLO")
        print("Your inventory:", items)

        # TODO:
        # Use Dialog window to ask for item to drop
        # Let that be stored in `dropItem`
        dropItem = None # Temporary

        # Better than using for loop for this
        if dropItem in items:
            items.remove(dropItem)
            print("Your", dropItem, "has been dropped. ")
            print("Your inventory", items)
        else:
            print("You don't have that item. Please enter another command.")


startButton = Button(
    frame1, text="Start game.", relief=RAISED, command=srtGame)
startButton.pack(fill=X)
GameOutput = Label(frame1, textvariable=strvar, relief=RAISED)
GameOutput.pack(fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixed code. I'm currently doing a course on python and this was out first project. I'm trying to learn some in depth info on python but didn't realise how many mistakes there were since this is my first day using tkinter.

Comment: Thank you for finding my answer useful. If I may, I would recommend first familiarising yourself with Python (on command line), and once you're quite confident, move to GUI. This prevents overwhelming a new learner. Unless of course you're short on time or something.